# How to subscribe to multiple Pusher public channels?

Tags: ios, swift, pusherswift

The default method for subscribing to a channel involves invoking the subscribe method of your client object:

```
pusher.subscribe('my-channel')
```

I have an array of channels e.g ['my-channel', 'test-channel']. The events will be generated in any of the channels and i need to listen from each of them.

```
// Class properties
let pusher = Pusher(key: Config.Constant.pusherAppKey)
var myChannel:PusherChannel?

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // PUSHER CONNECT?SUBSCRIBE
    self.pusher.connect()
    self.myChannel = self.pusher.subscribe(["temp_testing_channel", "all_test_channels"])
}
```

But there is an error:

```
Contextual type 'String' cannot be used with array literal
```

Comment: I don't want to create multiple channels variable and subscribe each to a different one, as number of channels will be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this feature is not available. As mentioned by the author. Here is the link

[GitHub issue link](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-swift/issues/33)